# Como saber si presionan el boton de retroceder en mi pagina usando js???

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, aplicación-web

necesito evitar que en una vista de mi pagina puedan volver atras. Como puedo saber si presionan el boton de retroceder en mi pagina usando js???

Comment: tenes que replantear tu aplicación, prohibir cosas a ese nivel no es bueno en cuanto a experiencia del usuario y dudo que los navegadores actuales lo soporten, mejor poner un aviso de que si van para atrás pierden los datos o algo así

Comment: humm si te endiendo, puede ser mejor opcion entonces poner un alert´como dices.

Comment: Más que evitar tienes que avisar de lo que puede pasar si abandonan la página actual. Lo puedes hacer con `window.onbeforeunload`